# Selenium can't locate the element, a search button using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I can't find a solution how this element cannot be found by using a selenium xpath. Other button on other websites always working just fine. Usually what I would normally do is, just open up a page and inspect the element and I would right click it and copy the xpath. Done.

But this website, www.gsc.com.my (a malaysian cinema booking site). Seems not able to find the button. Is it protected by another security layer?

[image]

Lets see the code below,

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path = './chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)  
driver.get('https://www.gsc.com.my')


driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnNext"]""").click()
```

The error Message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="btnNext"]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button is located inside an iframe, so you need to switch to that frame before clicking the button:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.switch_to.frame('getQuickFilter_ctrl_ifrBox')

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnNext"))).click()
```

Comment: Waiting is not necessary anymore in Selenium and considered bad practice.

Comment: @Bouke , Since when? can you share a link for the same?

Comment: @Bouke : Can you share any official links ?

Comment: @Bouke Why? You meant to say when you set an implicit wait?

Comment: I meant that waiting is not necessary when implicit wait duration has been set like `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Comment: @Bouke what if element becomes visible after few seconds?  Implicit wait would not wait for visibility unless you use old Legacy Firefox driver. When you reply me please put @ and followed by my name so that I will be notified.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: I used to set timeout to 30 seconds. Never had to use expected conditions. Just had a look at the documentation, `selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` might also be an option here.

Comment: @Bouke what if your element become visible after 2 seconds? Implicit wait is only element existence, its not for visibility or enabled so in such a condition you need to use explicit wait. If you have never faced a issue then you still haven't worked on dynamic environment like one element click makes another element to appear.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: When element exists but is not clickable yet, for instance because it is hidden or disabled, than you need to wait explicitly until the element is able to interact with. But I don't understand why that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two elements with id btnNext, you'll have to specify which of them using an index, 1 for the first, 2 for the second.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="btnNext"][1]""").click()`

Comment: Mmm, I'm wrong, element id is unique within document, the other one resides in an embedded iframe.

Comment: If none elements found, I'm not sure it make sense to search for the second one with the same approach

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this css selector :

```
div.container input#btnNext
```

Note that you will need to switch to iframe first , cause the check button is in a **iframe**.

For switching to iframe :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("getQuickFilter_ctrl_ifrBox"))
```

and for clicking on **check** Button

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
check_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container input#btnNext")))  
check_button.click()
```